# Can a process ask for x amount of time but take y amount instead?

Tags: operating-system, scheduler

If I am running a set of processes and they all want these burst times: 3, 5, 2 respectively, with the total expected time of execution being 10 time units.

Is it possible for one of the processes to take up more that what they ask for? For example even though it asked for 3 it took 11 instead because it was waiting on the user to enter some input. So the total execution time turns out to be 18.

This was all done in a non-preemptive cpu scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reality is that software has no idea how long anything will take - my CPU runs at a different "nominal speed" to your CPU, both our CPUs keep changing their speed for power management reasons, and the speed of software executed by both our CPUs is effected by things like what other CPUs are doing (especially for SMT/hyper-threading) and what other devices happen to be doing at the time (their effect on caches, shared RAM bandwidth, etc); and software can't predict the future (e.g. guess when an IRQ will occur and take some time and upset the cache contents, guess when a read from memory will take 10 times longer because there was a single bit error that ECC needed to correct, guess when the CPU will get hot and reduce its speed to avoid melting, etc). It is possible to record things like "start time, burst time and end time" as it happens (to generate historical data from the past that can be analysed) but typically these things are only seen in fabricated academic exercises that have nothing to do with reality.

*Note: I'm not saying fabricated academic exercises are bad - it's a useful tool to help learn basic theory before moving on to more advanced (and more realistic) theory.*

Instead; for a non-preemptive scheduler, tasks don't try to tell the scheduler how much time they think they might take - the task can't know this information and the scheduler can't do anything with that information (e.g. a non-preemptive scheduler can't preempt the task when it takes longer than it guessed it might take). For a non-preemptive scheduler; a task simply runs until it calls a kernel function that waits for something (e.g. `read()` that waits for data from disk or network, `sleep()` that waits for time to pass, etc) and when that happens the kernel function that was called ends up telling the scheduler that the task is waiting and doesn't need the CPU, and the scheduler finds a different task to run that can use the CPU; and if the task never calls a kernel function that waits for something then the task runs "forever".

Of course "the task runs forever" can be bad (not just for malicious code that deliberately hogs all CPU time as a denial of service attack, but also for normal tasks that have bugs), which is why (almost?) nobody uses non-preemptive schedulers. For example; if one (lower priority) task is doing a lot of heavy processing (e.g. spending hours generating a photo-realistic picture using ray tracing techniques) and another (higher priority) task stops waiting (e.g. because it was waiting for the user to press a key and the user did press a key) then you want the higher priority task to preempt the lower priority task "immediately" (e.g. because most users don't like it when it takes hours for software to respond to their actions).